# How do I get a Logitech MX 700 wireless mouse/keyboard recognized by Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, logitech-mouse

Is there anyway to get it working properly (even as a basic mouse)? The computer just keeps coming back with "Unknown Device". All of the results on google are asking for help or say that the support for this device has been dropped by microsoft and or Logitech. It seems like it should work as a basic wireless mouse though right?

//edit

I don't really care if the extended features work, it would just be nice to use it as a mouse/keyboard.

//update 2

It seems that the problem is 64bit Windows 7 only, it works fine in a 32bit environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that there were updates to Windows 7 that were preventing it from recognizing the "new" device.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to download drivers for that mouse to work correctly .
- For using it as a basic mouse try installing **Microsoft's IntelliPoint mouse driver**
- cool software which may be used as an alternative http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

**Note:** *Many people in other forums found 64 bit drivers for M700 from the Logitech home site , for more information go to Logitech website and then go to troubleshooting , there look for "Q: Windows 7 support for my Logitech product"*

Comment: I was looking at that option, seems that letting windows install it's updates 'fixed' the issue though.

Comment: glad to hear its solved, i was just about to google more

Comment: Thanks for the help! I wonder what the actual 'issue' was though...

Comment: The issue is caused because you don't have a 64 bit driver for your mouse. You i read in some forum that there is a 64bit driver for Windows XP. Unfortunately I am not able to find that for you. when you updated windows you have unknowingly installed Microsoft's IntelliPoint mouse driver.

Answer (score 0):

If the device isn't recognized automatically, you'll need to download the drivers from a trustworthy site and install it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This link for Setpoint driver-download worked for me under Windows7 64-bit:

http://www.logitech.com/pub/techsupport/mouse/setpoint480b.exe